# how to block pushedwebnews.com advertisement in browser?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, browser, adware

recently my browser (google chrome on windows 7 prof 64bit) keeps on popping up advertisement.

how could i block them? it's not actually virus but quite annoying...

I tried google a solution, [some web page](https://malwaretips.com/blogs/remove-pushedwebnews-com/) says it's a virus and need download and then install a software to remove it, but i'm not sure to do so, what if the so-call remover is a virus instead?

Comment: Such popus are often originated in rogue addons or extensions installed in the browser itself. You should check that first.

Comment: There are many extensions like adblocker, ublock origin, privacy badger, noscript etc to block ads.

Comment: This one sometimes brings in friends. I suggest to start by deep-scanning the computer with several well-known anti-virus products.

Comment: @athos - Start by backing up your Chrome profile then removing your Chrome profile.  This will verify if the behavior is due to a malicious extension or not.

Comment: @harrymc which ones are trustworthy?

Comment: None of the programs in installs are trustworthy. `pushedwebnews.com` is described as bordering on a malware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from the usual advice (get yourself an ad-blocker, disable rogue plug-ins, etc.), a way to accomplish this would be to implement a *sinkhole* for that domain.

In `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc` there is a file called `hosts`.  At the bottom of the file, add a line: `pushedwebnews.com 127.0.0.1` and save it.  This will effectively cut you off from that site forever.  Any attempt to navigate to that domain will fail.

**NOTE:** The `hosts` file is a protected Windows system file.  You will not be able to edit it by double-clicking it.  You must run `notepad.exe` (or whatever text editor of your choice) as an Administrator and browse to the file in order to make changes.